# Target multi-page content in Joomla 3.0?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I managed to do this by using an override for the category blog (`com_sontent/category/tmpl/blog.php`). There I used the following to differentiate between paginated and not-paginated content and to hide/show code elements via CSS.

```
<div class="category-desc pages<?php echo $this->pagination->get('limitstart'); ?>">
```

I would like to apply the same method to my template's index.php, for example wrap the component output in a container with a CSS class name indicating if the content is broken up into several pages or not.

This would make it possible to hide side bars from a paginated blog main page, whereas they would show in single (unpaginated) articles linked to from this page.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of PHP barely exists.

Comment: So what you really want to do: have a way for template to know if current category will have few pages of articles? Way to determinate if article was splited into few pages (article navigation detection)?